# I would like to run a command as a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts

I want to run this command as a bash script? how can i do that?

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall
```

Comment: On a side note, you don't need `sudo` to run `dpkg --get-selections`, and the "right" tool for that is `dpkg-query`, which gives you directly the informations you want without pipes etc: `dpkg-query -W -f '${Binary:package}\n'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create the script:

```
echo "sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall" > script.sh
```

Then, to give execute permission:

```
chmod 750 script.sh
```

Finally, to execute:

```
./script.sh
```

Comment: Good. Id suggest to use printf though as it's more universal that echo and more standard than echo from shell to shell

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are correct, but from the simplicity of your question I suspect those answers may be missing the boat on the info you actually need.

To run that command "as a script" you need to run it from the *command line*.  You actually don't need to make it as a script unless you plan to run it many times.  You can simply type that command into a terminal and it will run.  (Or copy and paste it, to be sure it is typed correctly.)

Search for "terminal" on your computer, open it up, paste or type in that command, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If the command line is new to you, a great introduction is "The Linux Command Line", available free online at http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `~/.bashrc`

```
function list_packages {
    dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall
}
```

Then

```
source ~/.bashrc
list_packages
```