# Can we make Executable Scripts to run on any Ubuntu machine?

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, package-management, scripts

### I am curious to know if there is a way we can execute several terminal commands by double clicking a file.

---

***Lets suppose these are the commands I want to execute on a terminal.***

```bsh
curl -s https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-core.asc | 

sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/brave-browser-release.gpg add -

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com `lsb_release -sc` main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave.list'

sudo apt update

sudo apt install brave-browser brave-keyring
```

> - But instead of running them one by one, I write them in a text-file with a file extension and save it on my computer.
> - Next I would like to just double click the file and it should execute these commands.
> - And if I share this file with others and they should be able to execute it by just double clicking it.

---

***Things I already know :***

> - Writing commands in a file with `#!/usr/bin/env bash` on the 1st line.
> - Making the file execute as a program `chmod -x <filename>`
> - Executing the files through terminal by `./<filename>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I would like to run a command as a bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/680905/i-would-like-to-run-a-command-as-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 3):

Modern operating systems move away from a very insecure approach where the user can double click any file and then have that file "execute something". Ubuntu, that uses Gnome Shell, is an example. The possibility to launch an executable file just by double clicking it in the file manager has deliberately been removed. Several file managers in other desktop environments, however, still allow that.

The proper way to make your script easily available to users for running is to ship a `.desktop` file with it. A `.desktop` file is a small text file that indicates to your desktop how to run the application, where it belongs in the menu system, how it can be searched, and what icon should be used.

For systemwide availability, the `.desktop` program should be installed under `/usr/share/applications`. If it has to be available only for selected users, then it should be installed under `.local/share/applications` in the accounts of each of the users that should be able to run the application.

In Ubuntu, and in various desktop environments, such `.desktop` files can be placed on the  user's Desktop. It then should be set to be "executable" and can then be run by double clicking the icon on the desktop.